# Can I use Spring security's CSRF feature only without using its LOGIN and LOGOUT Feature?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Can I use Spring security's CSRF feature without using its LOGIN and LOGOUT Feature?

I am using HTML page instead of JSP, I want Spring csrf token for all the POST requests I am making. 
For login we are using AWS Cognito.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use it with HTML as `Spring Security` has enable it by default. I've used it with `Thymeleaf` to work with server side.

Basically, you can simply name thymeleaf namespace in your HTML file like this.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
...
```

And the spring application you should import the dependencies below,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In the `application.yml` (or `application.properties`) file following configs.

```
spring:
    thymeleaf:
        enabled: true
        prefix: classpath:/static/ # This static directory located in the resource folder of maven directory structure and all the html and its css/js resources go in there.
        suffix: .html
        cache: false
        enable-spring-el-compiler: true
        check-template: true
        mode: HTML
        encoding: UTF-8
```

No you can add `CSRF` token to the web page just using two meta-tags in the header section of your html.

```
<meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}">
<meta name="_csrf_headerName" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}">
```

or, if you're using a `<form>` submit add this hidden input field into the `<form>`,

```
<input th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" type="hidden"/>
```

If, you have define them in a meta tag and need to make an Ajax request, here's the JQuery snippet;

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/url',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {"some": "data"},
        beforeSend: (jqXHR) => {
            jqXHR.setRequestHeader(
                $("meta[name='_csrf_headerName']").attr('content'),
                $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr('content'));

        },
        success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) => {
            // if success.
        },
        error: (jqXHR) => {
           // if error.
        },
        complete: (jqXHR, textStatus) => {
            // Anyway completed.
        }
});
```

Comment: Hi, I am using Spring MVC,Not spring boot for developing the app.
CSRF is not getting generated :(

Comment: Do you use spring security?

Comment: Well, if you use Spring-MVC, still should be able to configure `Thymeleaf `. But to get `_csrf.token` generated. You should have enabled `spring-security` 'csrf' configurations. Check this out -> https://hellokoding.com/spring-mvc-4-hello-world-example-with-xml-configuration-maven-and-thymeleaf/. Also `spring-boot` not-required.